# Getting an error while pushing message to IBM -MQ from apache camel spring application

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, ibm-mq

I am getting below error while pushing a message from apache camel component to IBM-MQ.

```
Error:-
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedMessageFormatException: JMSCC0050: The property name 'JMS_Solace_DeadMsgQueueEligible' is reserved and cannot be set.
```

Below are my pom jars i am using -

```
<camel-spring-boot-starter.version>2.21.0</camel-spring-boot-starter.version>
<camel-spring.version>2.21.0</camel-spring.version>
<camel-jms.version>2.21.0</camel-jms.version>
```

I am running the application using spring boot container.

Comment: I am reading the message from a solace queue.
dependency details
 <groupId>com.solacesystems</groupId>
    <artifactId>sol-jms</artifactId>
    <version>10.6.0</version>

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove that header, something a like:

```
   from solace
     removeHeaders("JMS_Solace*")
     to ibmmq
```

Comment: works when i call it from processor,
exchange.removeHeaders("*JMS*");